# Filled MS Word Template MergeFields not showing in result

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I'm trying to generate an MS Word output from an application from a template with MergeFields.  I'm using the code from [this CodeProject page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38575/Fill-Mergefields-in-docx-Documents-without-Microso) with the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.2.5 library in C#.

I have opened the document.xml from the docx ZIP and I see the sequence of five Runs () that constitute the merge field (see Before processing below).  The code from the CodeProject page does what it says it does and replaces the merge field with a text run (see After processing below).

My trouble is, when I save and open that docx in Word, I do not see any part of the replaced text.  I've been scratching my head, but have been unable to figure out what is wrong.  Can anyone offer some advice?  Thanks in advance!

Before processing:

```
<w:r w:rsidR="00314F5B">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:sz w:val="22"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00314F5B">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:sz w:val="22"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> MERGEFIELD  MyApp.PatientFirstName  \* MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00314F5B">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:sz w:val="22"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00314F5B">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:noProof/>
        <w:sz w:val="22"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>«MyApp.PatientFirstName»</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00314F5B">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:sz w:val="22"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
</w:r>
```

After processing:

```
<w:r w:rsidR="00314F5B">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:sz w:val="22" />
        <w:szCs w:val="22" />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>First</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:r>
```

Comment: The final markup has a run (w:r) inside another run. I don't think this is allowed. The outermost run should only contain the run properties (w:rPr) and the text (w:t).

Comment: Thanks!  That's something to check into at least.

Comment: @BradleySmith Your comment was indeed the answer. It appears to be an oversight with the original.  I've sent a note to the developer, but since the last update was 2011, not hoping for much.  Thanks again!